# Disable double confirmation for Simplenews

Tags: 7, emails

I have a simplenews registration block on my site. If people sign up for a newsletter, they receive a mail with a confirmation link. When they click on the link they come to a page with another confirmation button, which must be clicked if you realy want to register.

Thats the default behavior called Double-Opt-In in simplenews.

What I want for registration ist that you receive a mail with a confirmation link, if you click it you come to the page which says something like 'You are registered!'. I want to disable the need of this second button, any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need override the functionality of the simplenews module. Modify the simplenews confirmation form with a custom module using `hook_form_alter()`:

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if($form_id == 'simplenews_confirm_add_form') {
    $form['#attached']['js'] = array(
      drupal_get_path('module', 'mymodule') . '/simplenews_autosubmit.js',
    );
  }
}
```

Then create a JS file, **simplenews_autosubmit.js** in your custom module:

```
(function($) {
    window.setTimout(function(){ $('#simplenews-confirm-add-form').submit(); }, 3000);
})(jQuery);
```

You can set the 3000 to however long (in milliseconds) you want to wait between load and submit.

That should trigger a JS form submission upon loading the confirmation page.

Comment: Yeah that would work but I think this is a little bit dirty. I thought more of a hidden configuration or something... So another option would be to change a few lines in the module code, but this is dirty, too.

Comment: If you want to go that route, you could probably use `hook_form_alter()` to adjust the simplenews setting form & `hook_menu_alter() `to override the confirmation form path. That might get you something more to your liking. I threw out this solution as a minimally intrusive altercation of simplenews's default behavior.

Answer (score 2):

There's a considerably easier way to do this, which is also documented in the [README.txt](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/simplenews/tree/README.txt?h=6.x-2.x#n150) for 6.x-2.x, but apparently not in 7.x-1.x.

In short, just change the confirmation mail templates and append /ok to the URL token.

Comment: Any information if this also works in the 7.x version?

Comment: Yes, I wouldn't have mentioned it if it didn't :)

Comment: Oh Ok, i will try this way during this week, thank you very much :)